# Xcode 12.0.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code for ZendeskSDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, zendesk

I try to build the project in Xcode 12.0.1 but can't build with the error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"
I installed ZendeskSDK via cocoapods it seems that the error is generated by ZendeskSDK but can 't solve the issue

Frameworks/ZendeskSDK.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem solved this way;

Go to build settings and add type "arm64" in "Excluded Architectures"